# Access Denied Query XML SOAP Sharepoint

Tags: vba, excel, soap, sharepoint, runtime-error

The code worked very well, but these last days just stopped to work.
The .responseText is now:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

I tried with and without the line: `objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization"`  And got the same Error.
With and without User and Password at line `objXMLHTTP.Open`, and still the same problem, Access Denied.

Can you guys help me please?

```
Sub selectSharepoint()
Dim objXMLHTTP As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
Dim strBatchXml As String
Dim strSoapBody As String

UserName = "john@email.com"
Password = "123456"

Set objXMLHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", "https://ts.sharepoint.com/sites/2018_teste/_vti_bin/lists.asmx", False, UserName, Password
'objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", "https://ts.sharepoint.com/sites/2018_teste/_vti_bin/lists.asmx", False 'This way worked the same, and got the same error.
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "length"
'objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(UserName & ":" & Password) 'makes no effect, with or without Base64Encode
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems"

strSoapBody = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" & _
              "  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>" & _
              "     <soap:Body>" & _
              "         <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>" & _
              "             <listName>AllNames</listName>" & _
              "             <query>" & _
              "                 <Query xmlns=''>" & _
              "                     <Where>" & _
              "                          <Eq>" & _
              "                              <FieldRef Name='Name' />" & _
              "                              <Value Type='Text'>Cloe</Value>" & _
              "                          </Eq>" & _
              "                     </Where>" & _
              "                     <OrderBy>" & _
              "                         <FieldRef Name='ID' />" & _
              "                     </OrderBy>" & _
              "                 </Query>" & _
              "             </query>"
strSoapBody = strSoapBody & _
              "             <rowLimit>1</rowLimit>" & _
              "             <viewFields><ViewFields>" & _
              "                 <FieldRef xsi:type='s:string' Name='Name'></FieldRef>" & _
              "             </ViewFields></viewFields>" & _
              "         </GetListItems>" & _
              "     </soap:Body>" & _
              "  </soap:Envelope>"

objXMLHTTP.send strSoapBody

If objXMLHTTP.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox ("Error! " & Chr(10) & objXMLHTTP.responseText)
    End
Else
    tudo = objXMLHTTP.responseText
End If
End Sub
```

MsgBox Error:
[MsgBox Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1srK.png)

Comment: same problem, something with authentication on SPO is different..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need pass username or password, so try to keep this way:

```
objXMLHTTP.Open "POST", "https://ts.sharepoint.com/sites/2018_teste/_vti_bin/lists.asmx", False
```

Add a Host header (remember to replace "ts" with your domain):

```
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Host", "ts.sharepoint.com"
```

Check if all vars passed are valid, including XML syntax. In my case I was receiving the same error because I was trying to send an empty value to update a mandatory field on a UpdateListItems action.